# Optional values when ranging causes "xxpected map[string]interface {}; got interface {}" error in helm template

Tags: go, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, templating

I have a template.yaml file that looks like the below.

```
{{- $root := . }}
{{- range $service, $val := .Values.services }}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
  {{- if and (hasKey (.probes) "readiness") (hasKey (.probes).readiness "enabled") ((.probes).readiness.enabled) }}
readinessProbe:
  {{- if .probes.readiness.custom }}
  {{- toYaml .probes.readiness.custom | nindent 12 }}
  {{- else }}
  httpGet:
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.readiness "port") }}
    port: {{ required "probes.readiness.port is required" .probes.readiness.port }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.readiness "endpoint") }}
    path: "{{ required "probes.readiness.endpoint is required" .probes.readiness.endpoint }}"
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.readiness "scheme") }}
    scheme: {{ .probes.readiness.scheme }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.readiness "initialDelaySeconds") }}
  initialDelaySeconds: {{ .probes.readiness.initialDelaySeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.readiness "periodSeconds") }}
  periodSeconds: {{ .probes.readiness.periodSeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.readiness "timeoutSeconds") }}
  timeoutSeconds: {{ .probes.readiness.timeoutSeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.readiness "successThreshold") }}
  successThreshold: {{ .probes.readiness.successThreshold }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.readiness "failureThreshold") }}
  failureThreshold: {{ .probes.readiness.failureThreshold }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}

{{- else if $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.enabled }}
readinessProbe:
  {{- if $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.custom }}
  {{- toYaml $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.custom | nindent 12 }}
  {{- else }}
  httpGet:
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.readiness "port") }}
    port: {{ required "probes.readiness.port is required" $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.port }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.readiness "endpoint") }}
    path: "{{ required "probes.readiness.endpoint is required" $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.endpoint }}"
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.readiness "scheme") }}
    scheme: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.scheme }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.readiness "initialDelaySeconds") }}
  initialDelaySeconds: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.initialDelaySeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.readiness "periodSeconds") }}
  periodSeconds: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.periodSeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.readiness "timeoutSeconds") }}
  timeoutSeconds: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.timeoutSeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.readiness "successThreshold") }}
  successThreshold: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.successThreshold }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.readiness "failureThreshold") }}
  failureThreshold: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.readiness.failureThreshold }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if and (hasKey (.probes) "liveness") (hasKey (.probes).liveness "enabled") ((.probes).liveness.enabled) }}
  livenessProbe:
    {{- if .probes.liveness.custom }}
    {{- toYaml .probes.liveness.custom | nindent 12 }}
    {{- else }}
  httpGet:
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.liveness "port") }}
    port: {{ required "probes.liveness.port is required" .probes.liveness.port }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.liveness "endpoint") }}
    path: "{{ required "probes.liveness.endpoint is required" .probes.liveness.endpoint }}"
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.liveness "scheme") }}
    scheme: {{ .probes.liveness.scheme }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.liveness "initialDelaySeconds") }}
  initialDelaySeconds: {{ .probes.liveness.initialDelaySeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.liveness "periodSeconds") }}
  periodSeconds: {{ .probes.liveness.periodSeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.liveness "timeoutSeconds") }}
  timeoutSeconds: {{ .probes.liveness.timeoutSeconds }}
    {{- end }}
  successThreshold: 1
    {{- if (hasKey .probes.liveness "failureThreshold") }}
  failureThreshold: {{ .probes.liveness.failureThreshold }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
{{- else if $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.enabled }}
livenessProbe:
  {{- if $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.custom }}
  {{- toYaml $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.custom | nindent 12 }}
  {{- else }}
  httpGet:
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.liveness "port") }}
    port: {{ required "probes.liveness.port is required" $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.port }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.liveness "endpoint") }}
    path: "{{ required "probes.liveness.endpoint is required" $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.endpoint }}"
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.liveness "scheme") }}
    scheme: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.scheme }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.liveness "initialDelaySeconds") }}
  initialDelaySeconds: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.initialDelaySeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.liveness "periodSeconds") }}
  periodSeconds: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.periodSeconds }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.liveness "timeoutSeconds") }}
  timeoutSeconds: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.timeoutSeconds }}
    {{- end }}
  successThreshold: 1
    {{- if (hasKey $root.Values.global.probes.liveness "failureThreshold") }}
  failureThreshold: {{ $root.Values.global.probes.liveness.failureThreshold }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
```

I have a values.yaml that looks like this:

```
global:
  probes:
    readiness:
      enabled: true
      endpoint: /_readiness
      port: 8001
      scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 3
      failureThreshold: 2
    liveness:
      endpoint: /_liveness
      port: 8080
      enabled: true


services:
  kupkake-inator1:
    command:
      - "apps/run.py"
  kupkake-inator2:
    command:
      - "apps/run.py"
    probes:
      readiness:
        enabled: true
        endpoint: /_readiness
        port: 8001
        scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 3
        failureThreshold: 2
  kupkake-inator3:
    command:
      - "apps/run.py"
  kupkake-inator4:
    command:
      - "apps/run.py"
  kupkake-inator5:
    command:
      - "apps/run.py"
```

I get this error with helm template:

`Error: template: deployment.yaml:70:54: executing "templates/deployment.yaml" at <.probes>: wrong type for value; expected map[string]interface {}; got interface {}`

presumably because kupkake-inator2 has probes set, but only one of liveness or readiness, and not both.

how do i change my template yaml to do the following?

a. check to ensure that if a service does have .probes set, it has both a liveness AND a readiness one set.

or

b. if it has one, but not the other, take the missing one from the global section of the values file (`.global.probes.liveness` or `.global.probes.readiness`)

Please note, i am well aware the yaml is not valid kube yaml, i have removed most fields for conciseness.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. With your example `deployment.yaml` and `values.yaml`, `helm template` runs without errors and successfully produces five deployment manifests (using helm 3.10.2).

Comment: @larsks thanks for this, i was on 3.8.0, upgraded to 3.10.3 and the issue is no longer present. much appreciated. feel free to add this as an answer and i'll accept.